# loop of picture does not get placed correctly on website

Tags: html, image, slideshow

I have this code which creates a slideshow of pictures. The only problem is that it does not get placed correctly on the website:

```
    <html lang="en"> 
<head> 

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var pictureArchive= ['http://byggprojektoren.se/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Shanghai.jpg','http://byggprojektoren.se/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/logo_739047_web.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg']; 

window.onload=function() { 
 var o=document.createElement('img'); 
 o.setAttribute('id', 'image'); 
 o.setAttribute('src', pictureArchive[0]); 
 o.setAttribute('alt', ''); 
 document.body.appendChild(o); 
 rotate(pictureArchive.length); 
} 

function rotate(idx) { 
 if(idx>=pictureArchive.length) { 
  idx=0; 
 }
 document.getElementById('image').src=pictureArchive[idx++];
 timerID=setTimeout('rotate('+idx+')', 3000); 
} 
</script> 
<style type="text/css"> 
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
</body> 
</html>
```

URL:  [Website](http://byggprojektoren.se/)

Where in the code am I writing it wrong to place the picture where it is right now?

Would appreciate any kind of help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a div that serves as the "placeholder" for your images. Right now you do a `document.body.appendChild(o)` -which simply appends it to the existing body content.

just do this: `<div id="placeholder"></div>` and place this div where you want it in your page.
then call `document.getElementById("placeholder").appendChild(o);` and it will be placed inside your div

Comment: The thing is that I am using a wordpress theme which automaticly puts it in the position I want it to be. Is there any way that I can take away the **document.body.appendChild(o)** and then it automaticly places it correct? Thank you or your reply.

Comment: document.body.appendChild(o); will always append it to whatever else you already appended to the body - if you create your entire page with document.body.appendChild() you can insert it at the right spot - or you can use css to force a better position

Comment: Ok thank you or this help. I tried it but the images just disappeared for some strange reason.

Answer (score 0):

1) make closure to preserve global visibility from your staff :

```
( function(){
    window.onload = ...
    function(){...}
})();
```

2) Do not use "window.onload = ", always bind event listener window.addEventListener("load", function(){})

3) using "string-writen function is the road to hell, and timerID is not usefull variable (it's killed 
emmidiatly as function ends) write with normal functions:

```
setTimeout (function(){rotate(idx);},3000);
```

4) while idx is long-live thing place it var with normal scope, this makes setTimeout and other such things much easer to perform

```
var idx = 0;
function rotate(){
   if(idx...) idx = ...;
   setTimeout(rotate,3000); 
}
```

5) img.src not working, always do it by setting ATTRIBUTE image.setAttribute("src", images[idx])

6) idx++ in expression - worst style of programming, always do incremet explicitly in safe place of algorithm

```
image.setAttribute(idx); //no idx++(!!!) this line must do SINGLE work - setAttribute!!!
...
idx++ // !at the end of function, explicitly make code clear!
```

Comment: Sorry but I am new to programing so I dont really understand your corrections. Could you please apply them on the code I have written and just show the whole code? Thank you.